# the method says "should return an integer"

Tags: java

The error is that it says the method should return an integer.
I already returned it using the else statement! so why the error?

```
int pop()
        {   
            if(tos<0)
            {
                System.out.println("stack underflow");
                tos=-1;
            }
            else
                return stack[tos];
        }
```

Comment: Next time please make sure your example is complete and compiles.

Comment: You make think an integer will always return, but the compiler doesn't know that. When you code logic enters the `if statement` there is no return method.

Comment: ^ you only return in the **`else`**, never in the **`if`**.

Answer (score 6):

You don't return an integer on all the control paths.

Java explicitly forbids that.

You need to return something after `tos=-1;`, or throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

If the method enters the `if` it will never go to the `else` and won't return anything.

Comment: thanks!!! answer: I should be using a return statement in the IF statement too! silly mistakes!